# how to modify xml node using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

have that xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <applicationSettings>
  <AllSettings>
   <setting name="setting1" serializeAs="String">
    <value>myValue</value>
   </setting>
  </AllSettings>
 </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

and i want to change the value of `<value>` into something else, i have tried a couple method but can't find attribute `<value>`

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: <value> is an element and not an attribute. Try looking for element rather than an attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [XElement.ReplaceWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302711(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
XElement value = doc.Root.Descendants("value").SingleOrDefault();

value.ReplaceWith(new XElement("value", "newValue"));

doc.Save("data.xml");
```

or, as the other answer suggested, [XElement.SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setvalue(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
value.SetValue("newValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load your XML in a `XDocument` object (`System.Xml.Linq` namespace) and then change the value like this:

```
// load XML from string:
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
// or load XML from file:
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");

// change value
xdoc.Root.Element("applicationSettings").Element("AllSettings").Element("setting").Element("value").SetValue("myNewValue");
```